# Problems with SQL update statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010, dml

I have so far been implementing DML queries to update database tables successfully however, in this particular case I encountered a small problem. I have set the parameters which were used in the DML query however I get an exception

> No value given for one or more parameters

Here is the code:

```
Dim SQLQuery As String = <sql> 
            UPDATE QuestionAndAnswers
                 SET QuestionDescription = @QuestionDescription,
                     WorksheetID = @WorksheetID, 
                     CorrectAnswer = @CorrectAnswer,
                     IncorrectAnswer1 = @IncorrectAnswer1,
                     IncorrectAnswer2 = @IncorrectAnswer2,
                     IncorrectAnswer3 = @IncorrectAnswer3
                 WHERE QuestionID = @QuestionID
                </sql>.Value
            Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, Connection)
            Connection.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionDescription", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtQuestionDescription.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorksheetID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtWorksheetID.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CorrectAnswer", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtCorrectAnswer.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IncorrectAnswer1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtIncorrectAns1.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IncorrectAnswer2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtIncorrectAns2.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IncorrectAnswer3", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtIncorrectAns3.Text.Trim
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionID", txtQuestionID.Text.Trim)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'If rowsInserted > 0 Then
            '    MessageBox.Show("Record successfully updated", "Updated")
            '    ShowDataGridContentsWorksheetTable()
            'Else
            '    MessageBox.Show("Failed to update the record", "Failure")
            'End If
            Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel)
            Connection.Close()
        End Try
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `ms-access`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You are using an OleDBCommand object but the dbTypes from SQLServer for one thing.  if one of the TBs is empty that error would come up

Comment: @Plutonix But the thing is, I have placed code I pasted above within an IF statement, so if any textboxes were empty it would've showed me the message i put in the ELSE part of the IF statement. So If textboxes <> empty do (code shown) else custom error message.

Comment: `SqlDbType.Text` is for SQL Server and has a value of 18.  18 in OleDB maps to unsigned small int, so you are probably confusing it when it tries to convert string to a numeric.  You do not need references to `System.Data.SqlClient`, just OleDB

Comment: Please verify all your text boxes have values. And in case if you are passing some null value to a parameter then underlying table must allow this.

Comment: @Plutonix Any chance of a more 'visual' solution?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorksheetID", SqlDbType.Text)` the second param is the data type, you are using the wrong enum.  `SqlDbType` is for SQL Server. it should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorksheetID", OleDbType.VarChar)`  OleDb has several which map to System.String which is what textbox Text is.  Remove all your `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` because all of that is for SQLServer.  (that could very well be the cause since it is such a bad mismatch, but maybe not)

Comment: BTW, Intellisense should have offered you a valid `OleDbType` list as you typed.  Using `SqlDbType` should cause VS to flag the method as the obsolete `add(string,Object)` overload (green line, compiler warning)

Comment: @Plutonix I have done what you have suggested, however, the problem is still present.

Comment: What data type are WorksheetId and QuestionId in the database?  Those would typically be numeric not Text and QuestionId probably ought to be an autoincrement.  (pretty flat db model for something with a clear 1:m relationship)

Comment: @Plutonix Yes Question ID is auto increment, but worksheet ID is text

Comment: Since you use AddWithValue, pass the correct type: convert the text to integer (`Convert.ToInt32()`  **not** `Val`).  VB usually catches those, but...  Other than that, set a breakpoint on `ExecuteNonQuery` and examine the parameters collection in the debugger, *provided the error hasnt changed from the other fixes* it should be easy to see which one has a null/Nothing/empty value

Comment: ...errr you *did* change **all** the `SqlDbType` items to 'OleDbType` right?